# Envío y respuesta de datos entre páginas con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quisiera saber si existe la forma de hacer que dos páginas se comuniquen de la forma como hacen algunas para iniciar sesión por ejemplo con otros servicios como Google o Facebook.

En mi caso puntual, tengo una página **A** en mi aplicativo y de igual forma una página **B**, en la página **A** permitir la consulta de un cliente con Tipo de documento y número de documento, lo consulto y si no existe, llamo (mediante un iframe) la página **B**, la cual permite crearlo, quiero poder enviar los datos (tipo documento y número documento) a la página **B**, esto lo estoy haciendo enviando variables por get en el SRC que llama el iframe (`src="/pagina1/pagina1.aspx?TD=1&ND=123456789"`).

Listo, supongamos que el envío de datos lo podría tener solucionado así; en la página **B** leo esos parámetros y tomo los valores, y creo el cliente, pero no sé cómo puedo hacer para que ahora, la página **B** le diga a la **A** que ya se creó el cliente y le envie los datos de este, y sea la página **A** la que emita el mensaje de creación y lea ahora estos datos con los que fue creado.

¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

---

> Solución

Para mi funcionó [window.postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

El ejemplo que voy a colocar acá lo tome de [esta página](https://www.returngis.net/2013/05/html-5-web-messaging-window-postmessage/)

[Aquí](https://robertnyman.com/html5/postMessage/postMessage.html) otro ejemplo.

> Página A

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cross-origin Communication - Sender</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
console.log(location);
        var domain = 'http://localhost:7639';
  var myPopup = window.open(domain + '/B.html', 'Listener Window');
  var counter = 1;

  setInterval(function () {
      var message = 'Hello guest number ' + counter + '!';
      console.log('Sending message: ' + message);
      myPopup.postMessage(message, domain);
      counter++;
  }, 5000);

  window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
      if (event.origin !== domain) return;
      console.log('Received response: ', event.data);
  }, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Página B

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cross-origin Communication - Sender</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
  //respond to events
  window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
      if (event.origin != 'http://localhost:7639') return;
      var asd = { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" }
      console.log('message received: ' + event.data, event);
      event.source.postMessage(asd, event.origin);
  }, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podrias usar Ajax

Comment: Ya lo hago, pero para las transacciones frente al servidor, no sé cómo hacerla en páginas por ejemplo solo html y js

Comment: Encontré esto, no sé si podria ayudar https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

> Solución

Para mi funcionó [window.postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

El ejemplo que voy a colocar acá lo tome de [esta página](https://www.returngis.net/2013/05/html-5-web-messaging-window-postmessage/)

[Aquí](https://robertnyman.com/html5/postMessage/postMessage.html) otro ejemplo.

> Página A

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cross-origin Communication - Sender</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
console.log(location);
        var domain = 'http://localhost:7639';
  var myPopup = window.open(domain + '/B.html', 'Listener Window');
  var counter = 1;

  setInterval(function () {
      var message = 'Hello guest number ' + counter + '!';
      console.log('Sending message: ' + message);
      myPopup.postMessage(message, domain);
      counter++;
  }, 5000);

  window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
      if (event.origin !== domain) return;
      console.log('Received response: ', event.data);
  }, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Página B

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cross-origin Communication - Sender</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
  //respond to events
  window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
      if (event.origin != 'http://localhost:7639') return;
      var asd = { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" }
      console.log('message received: ' + event.data, event);
      event.source.postMessage(asd, event.origin);
  }, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podría utilizar `parent` de javascript, el cual permite acceder a la ventana padre que contiene el `iframe`.

Este código sería el que ejecutaría el `iframe`, lo que hace es redirigir la pagina "padre", y la redirecciona a esta misma, pero pasando le atributos por `get`, los cuales tendría que tratar en la página padre:

```
<script>
     parent.location.href = "pagina_padre.php?id_de_cliente_creado=25";
</script>
```

Ahora en la pagina padre debería verificar, si al cargar le enviaron datos por `get` y hacer con esto lo que usted desee.

Comment: Pero tendría que recargar la página, eso no es lo que quiero, quiero poder hacer algo como cuando una página usa facebook para iniciar sesión, te envía a un tooltip y se queda esperando a esa pagina (facebook) le responda con tus datos registrados

Comment: Mira esto https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage